# sqlite log queries that produce errors

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm writing an application in C that uses sqlite3. I'd like all queries and errors to be logged passively to stderr for debugging.

Say I have this code (error handling omitted):

```
void main(void)
{
    sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG, errorLogCallback, NULL);
    sqlite3 *db = NULL;
    sqlite3_open_v2("main.db3", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    sqlite3_trace_v2(db, SQLITE_TRACE_STMT, tracer, NULL);

    // this code cannot change
    sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM users", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM users_nonexistant", NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

static void errorLogCallback(void *, int iErrCode, const char *zMsg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "(%d) %s\n", iErrCode, zMsg);
}

static int tracer(unsigned, void*, void *p, void*)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = (sqlite3_stmt*)p;
    char *sql = sqlite3_expanded_sql(stmt);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", sql);
    sqlite3_free(sql);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM users
(1) no such table: users_nonexistant
```

How can I make it output this?

```
SELECT * FROM users
SELECT * FROM users_nonexisant
(1) no such table: users_nonexistant
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading the documentation for [sqlite3_config](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/config.html) lead to this [page about Configuration Options](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_covering_index_scan.html),

> #### SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG
>
> The `SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG` option is used to configure the SQLite global error log. The `SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG` option takes two arguments: a pointer to a function with a call signature of `void (*)(void*, int, const char*)`, and a pointer to `void`. If the function pointer is not `NULL`, it is invoked by `sqlite3_log()` to process each logging event. If the function pointer is `NULL`, the `sqlite3_log()` interface becomes a no-op.

> **The void pointer that is the second argument to `SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG` is passed through as the first parameter to the application-defined logger function whenever that function is invoked**. The second parameter to the logger function is a copy of the first parameter to the corresponding `sqlite3_log()` call and is intended to be a result code or an extended result code. The third parameter passed to the logger is log message after formatting via `sqlite3_snprintf()`. The SQLite logging interface is not reentrant; the logger function supplied by the application must not invoke any SQLite interface. In a multi-threaded application, the application-defined logger function must be threadsafe.

which mean you can pass a [`char** pStatement`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char**+pStatement) which will point to the `char*` sql statement to be executed.

```
//...
int main(void)
{
    char** pStatement=NULL;
    sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG, errorLogCallback, pStatement);
    sqlite3 *db = NULL;
    sqlite3_open_v2("main.db3", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    sqlite3_trace_v2(db, SQLITE_TRACE_STMT, tracer, NULL);

    const char *statement="SELECT * FROM users";
    pStatement=(char**)&statement;
    sqlite3_exec(db,statement , NULL, NULL, NULL);

    const char *faultyStatement="SELECT * FROM users_nonexistant";
    pStatement=(char**)&faultyStatement;
    sqlite3_exec(db, faultyStatement, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

static void errorLogCallback(void * pStatement, int iErrCode, const char *zMsg
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n(%d) %s\n",*(char**)pStatement, iErrCode, zMsg);
}
//...
```

**Disclaimer**: This is an untested pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.This would definitely print out the right info, but I don't want to write that extra code for *every* `sqlite3_exec` statement. I've added a comment, `// this code cannot change` to make this more obvious.

Comment: `sqlite3_exec` itself is already a wrapper for `prepare`, `step` and `finalize`, you could write a wrapper function that also set the pointer for the current statement

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah, I know I *could* write a wrapper around all sqlite3 calls. But this is at work where I can't exactly change all 100+ call sites *and* send out a company-wide email telling everyone to use my new API. I appreciate the help, but it sounds like what I want is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The statement tracer is called only for statements that actually run.

There is no built-in mechanism to log SQL statements before they have been compiled.
If you cannot modify the `sqlite3_exec` calls, you have to change the source code of SQLite and add the log call there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I suspected this was the case, but I hoped otherwise. Patching the source is an option, but probably not worth it, maintenance-wise. I'll just live with what I have.